# Laravel ¦ Store sets of 2 values on a string for parsing and display them later

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, parsing

I have this mysql table (with more columns actually) :

```
Office  |  Employees                                | 
------------------------------------------------------
Paris   |  John:901001; Mary:901002                 |     
NY      |  Charles:902002                           |
Rome    |  Bob:903001; John:903002; Charles:903003  |
```

And I would like to display the employees for each of the office's views, like this, on different rows :

```
John  |  901001 | 
-----------------
Mary  |  901002 |
```

How do I do it? How do I parse the data?

Comment: Don't parse; instead normalize the data once and reap the benefits forever :-)

Comment: Don't do this. You're essentially negating any benefit of using a relational database and an ORM like Eloquent.

Comment: mm maybe I could just have "John;901001; Mary;901002..etc" and split the array in sets of two ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I just understood why Eloquent is nice.

I can create another model for the "employees" and associate them to each office.